# _M_ construct null not valid error when trying to implement multi threaded queue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to implement a priority queue using using a simple linear approach as explained in [Art of Multiprocessor programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008CYT5TS). I'm new to c++ and have difficulty troubleshooting.

I've implemented two template classes and am testing them using a simple test method. As I'm not able to pin point the error, I'm pasting all the three classes below for reference.

I know that `_M_ construct null not valid` comes when trying to construct a string using `nullptr`, but am not sure where I'm doing that.

The three classes created are given below:

## bin.h

```
#include <mutex>
#include <deque>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace priority
{
    template<typename T>
    class Bin
    {
    private:
        std::deque<T> v;
        std::mutex m;
    public:
        Bin() {
        }

        Bin(const Bin &o) {
            
        }

        const Bin &operator=(const Bin &other) {
            return *this;
        }

        void put(T item) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            v.push_back(item);
        }

        T *get() {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            if (v.size() == 0) {
                return nullptr;
            }
            else {
                T val = v.front();
                T *ptr_val = &(val);
                v.pop_front();
                return ptr_val;
            }
        }

        bool isEmpty() {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            return v.size() == 0;
        }
        
    };  
}
```

## SimpleLinear.h

```
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "Bin.h"

namespace priority
{   
    template<typename T>
    class SimpleLinear
    {
    private:
        int range;
        std::vector<Bin<T>> pqueue;
    public:
        SimpleLinear(int range){
            this->range = range;

            for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
            {
                pqueue.push_back(Bin<T>());
            }

        }

        void add(T item, int key) {
            pqueue[key].put(item);
        }

        T removeMin() {
            for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
            {
                T *item = pqueue[i].get();
                if (item != nullptr) {
                    return *item;
                }
            }
            return nullptr;
        }
        
    };
}
```

## test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include "SimpleLinear.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace priority;

void te(SimpleLinear<string> s, int thread_id) {

    s.add("sundar"+to_string(thread_id), thread_id);
    s.add("akshaya"+to_string(thread_id), 3);
    s.add("anirudh"+to_string(thread_id), 1);
    s.add("aaditya"+to_string(thread_id), 5);
    cout << s.removeMin() << endl;
    cout << s.removeMin() << endl;
    cout << s.removeMin() << endl;

}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   

    SimpleLinear<string> s(100);
    std::vector<std::thread> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {   
        // if (i % 2 == 0)
            v.push_back(thread(te, std::ref(s), i));
        // else
            // v.push_back(thread(t, std::ref(s), i));

        
    }
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
terminate called recursively
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: If you want to create an empty string, just do e.g. `std::string()`. Or for a generic type `T` do `T()`.

Comment: `removeMin` is returning `nullptr`.  Change it to `return T();`

Comment: Your problem is that you think (I'm guessing) `nullptr` means "no object". That's wrong, `nullptr` just means "null *pointer*". In C++ (unlike languages like C# and Java) there is no such thing as "no object".

Comment: actually.. I'm really sorry about that code.. I 've posted the wrong code... I've updated it

Comment: SimpleLinear isn't thread safe - you're adding items from multiple threads into a std::vector without locking

Comment: @UKMonkey In simple linear, I'm just calling the put of Bin right which is thread safe, so should I lock there as well?

Comment: `pqueue[key].put(item);` is a call to put on pqueue.  pqueue isn't thread safe.
Bin doesn't need to be thread safe, as you don't have multiple threads trying to read/write to any one instance at the same time

Comment: Now after your edit you have *undefined behavior* instead, as you return pointers to local variables. ***Don't*** update your question to "fix" the code. That pull the rugs out under our feet, so to say. It makes our comments and possible answers wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason it crashes is that in `SimpleLinear<T>::removeMin` when `T` is `std::string`, `return nullptr` constructs a string from `nullptr`. `basic_string::_M_construct null not valid` basically says 
that `std::string(nullptr)` was invoked.

---

Another reason it may crash is that `get` function returns a pointer to a local variable. Local variables get destroyed when the function returns. This leads to undefined behavior.

A fix:

```
bool get(T& result) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if (v.empty()) 
        return false;
    result = v.front();
    v.pop_front();
    return true;
}
```

And invoke it like:

```
T removeMin() {
    T result;
    for(int i = 0; i < range; i++)
        if(pqueue[i].get(result))    
            break;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. I understand the answer you've given... but I don't understand the fix you've proposed... I need the get method to return the result, not get is as a argument in `Bin.h`

Comment: @anirudh Updated the answer for you.

Comment: oh.. thats a great way to get a result... sorry I'm new to c++ and so still confused about when to use pass by reference and passing pointers.. Thanks again..